# Does voice and video calling have javascript event listeners like the chat event listerners in Azure Communication Service?

Tags: azure, events, real-time, azure-eventgrid, azure-communication-services

I am currently working on a PoC communication application. I have been researching Azure Communication Service (ACS) a lot and find it a promising service to integrate into my application.

Just like real-time chatting, I want to have real-time incoming voice and video calls with ACS. I noticed this was doable with the [Event Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/voice-video-calling/handle-calling-events) and SignalR, but I would like to know if it could also be done, like how they did it with real-time chatting. Reference to how chats do real-time, I found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/concepts/chat/concepts#real-time-notifications) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/chat/get-started?tabs=windows&pivots=programming-language-javascript#receive-chat-messages-from-a-chat-thread).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's totally possible, see the official [quickstart](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/communication-services-javascript-quickstarts/blob/0447f535279b10b1c042ce95e1fe8b06caf89700/add-chat/client.js#L46-L49):

```js
chatClient.startRealtimeNotifications();
chatClient.on("chatMessageReceived", async (e) => {
    console.log("Notification chatMessageReceived!");
});
```

The model you'll get looks like this:

```js
export interface ChatMessageReceivedEvent extends BaseChatMessageEvent {
    /**
     * Content of the message.
     */
    message: string;
    /**
     * Metadata of the message.
     */
    metadata: Record<string, string>;
}
```

If you're interested in building it with .NET, you can take a look at my [ASP.NET Blazor + SignalR chat sample](https://github.com/petrsvihlik/azure-communication-chat-blazor-net).

Comment: The quickstart is a great one big place with all feature samples of Azure Communication. The one-on-one calling sample also seemed to have javascript event handling for incoming calls just like how it works with chatting. 

I am not sure what you meant with the model example you send, but this quickstart is already really helpful. I will accept this answer. Thank you

Comment: By model I mean what you'll get in `async (e)` -> the `e` will have the form of the `ChatMessageReceivedEvent`.